# Replace group of similor colored pixels with image - iOS

Tags: ios, pixel, mask, data-augmentation

I am using the fritz person model and from that, I am getting one mask image of a person. Now, I want to add one different image on that mask. So, basically, I want to replace mask with some different image or in other words you can say I want to replace a group of common colored pixels with some image.

I researched a lot but didn't find anything.
I am also adding the mask image which I have got after using fritz person model for reference.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "fritz person model?" What does your code look like? What frameworks are you using or would like to use (`UIKit`, `CoreImage`, `Vision`)?

Comment: https://www.fritz.ai/features/image-segmentation.html see this. I have used Image segmentation for person model.

Comment: Are you using the code found [here](https://github.com/fritzlabs/heartbeat-ios/blob/master/Heartbeat/Source/Modules/ImageSegmentation/ImageSegmentationViewController.swift)?

Comment: Yes I am using that code only